# Rails 4, Postgres and time intervals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, intervals

Is there a way to store a time interval from a Rails 4 app in a single column in Postgres? Let's say users were booking a Widget model and I needed to store timeframes of 15 minutes up to 6 hours, and to be able to query them easily.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441775/store-time-interval-in-postgresql-from-rails